# Use PowerShell to copy all files in many folders to a single folder

Tags: powershell, copy-item

```
Copy-Item -Path D:\DB-DNLD\ -Filter *.csv -Destination D:\Dump\CSV -Recurse
```

I used this command, but it copied all .csv files along with existing folder structures, but my intention is just to copy all CSV to new single destination folder excluding source folder structures.

Answer (score 2):

The Copy-Item cmdlet will maintain the tree structure. If you want to flatten the structure, you can locate the items with Get-ChildItem cmdlet then pipe that to a loop where each file it copied to the destinition folder individually.

```
dir -Path D:\DB-DNLD\ -Filter *.csv -Recurse | ForEach-Object { Copy-Item $_.FullName D:\Dump\CSV }
```